# Inertia.js (React) page loaded event required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inertiajs

I need to change some geometry after Inertia.js page loaded.
In pure JS it is DOMContentLoaded event.
Guess Inertia.js' page similar to React component and `componentDidMount` will applicable for this.
The problems is - `componentDidMount` is method for `React.Component` class, but Inertia.js' page just a function, not class.
How to catch page loaded event on Inertia.js page?